# Decrypt PCLCrypto data from Xamarin Portable in C# Console

Tags: c#, encryption, xamarin

By encrypting data using PCLCrypto following this tutorial:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4088a7/using-cryptography-in-portable-xamarin-formswindows-phone/

The only change I made is the salt, that is set by my self:

```
byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("We#@%ds51&s9$$$8");
```

And I am unable to decrypt the result in a Console application:

```
        public static string Decrypt(string text, byte[] key, int keysize = 128, int blocksize = 128, CipherMode cipher = CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = blocksize;
        aes.KeySize = keysize;
        aes.Mode = cipher;
        aes.Padding = padding;

        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("We#@%ds51&s9$$$8");

        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        {

            byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
            decrypt.Dispose();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!